# How Do I loop through multiple stock data and after processing it, display it in one single .csv file at the end in Python? My data is from Yahoo Fin

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, export-to-csv, yahoo-finance

```
from numpy import array
import talib
import yfinance as yf
from tabulate import tabulate
import pandas as pd

stock_list=['ICICIBANK.NS','COALINDIA.NS','RELIANCE.NS']

appended_data={}

for stock in stock_list:

 data= yf.download(stock,period='1y', interval='1d')

 morning_star = talib.CDLMORNINGSTAR(data['Open'], data['High'], data['Low'], data['Close'])
 two_crows = talib.CDL2CROWS(data['Open'], data['High'], data['Low'], data['Close'])
 three_crows = talib.CDL3BLACKCROWS(data['Open'], data['High'], data['Low'], data['Close'])

 data['Stock Name']= stock
 data['Morning Star'] = morning_star
 data['Two Crows'] = two_crows
 data['Three Black Crows']= three_crows


 dict = {'Stock Name': data['Stock Name'],
    'Open' : data['Open'],
    'High' : data['High'],
    'Low': data['Low'],
    'Close':data['Close'],
    'Morning Star': data['Morning Star'],
    'Two Crows':data['Two Crows'],
    'Three Black Crows':data['Three Black Crows']
}

 appended_data.update(dict)
df= pd.DataFrame(appended_data)
df_latest= df.tail(5)
df_latest.to_csv('Candlestick Screener Data.csv')
```

Hello,
I'm super new to programming in general in Python and I'm having real trouble figuring out one thing.

When I run the above code that I've written I end up with data only for the last iteration from stock_list= ['ICICIBANK.NS','COALINDIA.NS','RELIANCE.NS'] in my CSV file. Whereas data from the first two loop iterations are missing.

The overall idea is to pull multiple datasets, process the collected data and finally store all that data in one single CSV file for me to look at.

I have a basic idea of what's missing but I'm not able to put it into code and make it work.
I'd really appreciate it if someone could look into it and help me out along with some explanantion (if possible).

Thank you

Comment: `df_latest= df.tail(5)` do you really want just the last five rows?

Comment: Yes, from each dataset I need the last 5

Comment: The problem is that the data is overwritten and only the data from the last FOR loop iteration is displayed and stored in the CSV. Whereas I want data from all the iterations of the FOR loop which contains data for multiple stocks.

Answer (score 0):

So the reason your `data` only contains the last item is because, in each loop iteration, it gets overwritten with the stuff from that iteration.

Calling `update` on your `append_data` dict doesn't work, because the "new" dict has the same field names as the old, so it'll just overwrite them!

Now given that eventually you want to write it all to a csv, you'll want to collect the data in a pandas DataFrame. If I remember correctly, a dataframe can be built from a *list* of *dictionaries* as the data.

So here's what you can do: Before the `for` loop, create an empty list like so

```py
dict_list = []
```

and then inside the loop, instead of your `update` call, you say

```py
dict_list.append(dict)
```

And then you should be able to do

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(dict_list)
```

Comment: Hi, I tried doing this earlier but had no luck with it.